# What is the difference between Crossbreeding, Outbreeding and Outcrossing?

Tags: zoology, terminology

I only found one book which isn't a textbook  named *Storey's Illustrated Guide to 96 Horse Breeds of North America By Judith Dutson* (not sure if it is good enough to follow) that defined these terms.

> Outbreeding/ outcrossing is deliberately crossing one line of horse within a breed to a very distant or unrelated line. The term is also occasionally used as a synonym for crossbreeding.
>
> Crossbreeding is the deliberate crossing of horses of different breeds.

**My understanding:**

Outbreeding or Outcrossing is the mating between two individuals of a  breed but different varieties/sub-varieties.

Crossbreeding is the mating between two individuals of different breeds (could be intraspecific or interspecific as well).

*Are these definitions correct?*

Comment: The term cross breeding is a bit broader term , whereas outbreeding is more specific.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer in keywords**

Inbreeding : related individual,same breed

Outbreeding

1. Cross breeding : between different breeds
2. Outcrossing : unrelated individual,same breed,no common ancestor

**Detailed answer**

Inbreeding it is a mating within the same breed between different superior male and superior female. Inbreeding between close relatives can cause inbreeding depression like decreased Vigour , fertility and productivity. It is therefore advisable to mte superior animals of different population of the same breed .

Outbreeding is mating between unrelated animals of same or different breeds.

Outcrossing is mating between unrelated animals of same breed with no common ancestor for at least 4 to 6 generation. Offspring formed from such a cross is called out cross .

Cross breeding is mating between superior animals of different breeds for raising new breeds for improving local breeds.

Please note: **Outcrossing and
cross breeding are two types of Outbreeding.**

If you have any further doubts please ask .
Hope it helps!!

Comment: Welcome. If you can add the definition of Outcrossing, and add appropriate resources (wikipedia would suffice here I guess, given the textbook-question-like-nature of this post) this would make a great answer (imho - I'm not an expert on this topic). For now, no upvote and just a banner.

Comment: The link is broken. Also, please do not post a link only answer. Link only should better be posted as comments.

Comment: I have updated my answer as suggested.